# Encode uploaded video files using php to .flv

Tags: php, video, flv, joomla1.5, video-encoding

My platform is PHP JOOMLA MYSQL. I want to encode and load uploaded video files of different formats to .flv. I want this to implement in a video upload site where the users can see the videos in front-end after uploading and also I want to implement download options for them in mp4 and flv. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance to have a good reply for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the powerful [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) to encode the videos once they're uploaded to your server.

And here's a nice [tutorial](http://youtubeclone.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/).

Comment: thanks a lot to take your time..I will get back to you after checking

Comment: At first I want to try it in my wamp server in my local, do you think the wamp server already had this ffmpeg installed so that I could run this above tutorial code there to get the video encoded with no other efforts

Comment: I would imagine you have to install it first, it's a 3rd party plugin so chances are it doesn't ship with wamp. I could be wrong though! :)